# How to disable the trash can in KDE

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, rm, trash

From what I gather, the idea of a "trash can" is of Windows descent, and was to make a user's life easier. However, when I go to delete a file, *I don't hit delete unless I know I don't need it and will never need it ever again. Period.* I'm currently running OpenSuse and the trash can is a confusing "feature" (as I can't seem to find WHERE it is) that sometimes even creates cute little directories on my flash drives for trash.

Basically put, I don't like the trash can idea. Is there a way I can "turn it off"? I'm assuming it's a filesystem thing, so it might be harder to do then I predict. Basically, I would like to perform a `rm -rf` on the file that is selected (`-r` in case it is a directory). Is this at all possible?

Comment: This is in a desktop environment I take it? Which one?

Comment: Currently I'm using KDE

Comment: 'How to disable the trash can under KDE 4?' as new title?

Comment: @max, changed the title and added the kde tag. However, I'd like to know how to do this is all popular environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under KDE you can hit `shift`+`del` to directly delete selected files (or directories). Or you can press `shift` while chosing 'move to trash ...' in the context menu, which has the same effect.

IIRC this also works under Windows.

Probably there is some trash-properties dialog under KDE to globally disable the trash feature. [It is possible to configure it in Dolphin](https://web.archive.org/web/20230430011901/http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=91082), but perhaps there is also a more general solution in KDE available.

Comment: I'm currently using dolphin and the method described in the post didn't fully work. I'm guessing that was with a previous version.

Answer (score 7):

You can redefine Delete key action in Dolphin. Settings->Configure Shortcuts 
Delete key is now actually delete

Also remove Trash entry from Places panel.
And your Dolphin is "Move to trash" free.

Actually you still have it on file/foldercontext menu..

Comment: +1, this is the only answer which attempts to address the OP's objective.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about KDE, but many DEs support the `shift+del` for removal of files bypassing the trash.